# Unit test of "CodeIgniter Controller"

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not getting a way to apply unit test on "codeigniter controller". I found many examples but nobody gives an exact solution. If you have any one please suggest.

Comment: I went through many blogs and documents every document has given only how to write test cases for model not controller.

Comment: Which is good, you should do your research before posting here, but can you provide a list of what you have tried?

Comment: Its not like that Every scenario says load model and test some given apis which use to test  but What i looking is if you are going to test a controller you have to call controller class from some where else class that thing I am not getting how to do, I did google much some stack over flow answer says its impossible. Tell me what should i do

Comment: Because test of CodeIgniter controller is difficult. This might help you: https://github.com/kenjis/ci-app-for-ci-phpunit-test/tree/master/application/tests/controllers But if you think a class is a unit, some of them may not be true unit tests.